# Can the buttons on a microwave's touchpad be repaired?

Tags: repair

I have a built-in Bosch HMD8451UC/01 microwave. Two buttons on the control pad are not working (the most used buttons to open and close the drawer). The rest of the buttons work. I tried searching for replacement control panel/board, but can't find any seller that sells the replacement board (there are sellers selling the panel fascia or outer shell, but not the electronics as far as I can tell).

Is there any way to fix the buttons themselves? I believe the buttons are mechanical vs. capacitive as when pressed there is some deflection in the panel. Any ideas? I'd hate to replace the entire microwave, which is expensive since it is the built-in type.

I can pull open the drawer manually. when I lightly push the drawer in, it closes automatically (the motor pulls the drawer close). However, it does not close automatically if I press the close button (nothing happens).

Comment: Is this [part listing](https://www.fix.com/parts/microwave/bosch/fix11705224/panel-facia-00798312/?SourceCode=1&ModelNum=HMD8451UC&ModelID=6867024) incorrect? It may be prohibitively expensive, but it seems correct.

Comment: I had similar problems with a KitchenAid oven. Found a company that replaces the keypads and refurbishes the rest of the board. Not perfect (started having other problems several months later) but got another couple of years out of the oven (and still going for now). https://www.fixyourboard.com/ - no connection except as a satisfied customer.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Bosch directly to see if they sell a replacement control panel? You'd pay the OEM premium, but it may be less than a full replacement. (Yes, I know this is an old question, but it's been brought back to the surface...)

Answer (score 4):

Buttons of this sort tend to operate by flexing a bubble of plastic material. The bubbles have a finite duty cycle, and when they fail they're broken. **There's no practical way to repair them** without some sort of retrofit replacement, which would be cumbersome, ugly and potentially dangerous.

Unfortunately you're the victim of our throwaway society. I suggest looking for a replacement unit from a company with known repair support.

Answer (score 0):

Probability says, it is not the open/close buttons.

It is probably the Gear (motor)

If you push Open, nothing happens.

If you open manually and push close nothing happens.

It would be rare that two buttons go bad at same time. But what they have in common is the Gear/Motor that might be bad.

[image: gear]

Unfortunately it costs $200 at

[Gear](https://www.applianceparts4all.com/bosch-gear-00658492)

Comment: The response to your comment question indicates that the drive motor is ok.

Comment: As @isherwood already said, the other responses already indicate the drive motor is OK. In addition, two buttons that (a) are probably next to each other (so possibly common failure piece) and (b) that are used extremely frequently, are likely to fail around the same time.